# PySpark: how to use `StringIndexer` to do label encoding with the string array column

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

As we know, we can do `LabelEncoder()` by `StringIndexer` in the string column, but if want to do `LabelEncoder()` on string array column, it is not easy to implement.

```
# input
df.show()

+--------------------------------------+
|                                  tags|
+--------------------------------------+
|        [industry, display, Merchants]|
|    [smart, swallow, game, Experience]|
|             [social, picture, social]|
|        [default, game, us, adventure]|
| [financial management, loan, product]|
|       [system, profile, optimization]|

...
# After do LabelEncoder() on `tags` column 
...

+--------------------------------------+
|                                  tags|
+--------------------------------------+
|                             [0, 1, 2]|
|                          [3, 4, 4, 5]|
|                             [6, 7, 6]|
|                         [8, 4, 9, 10]|
|                          [11, 12, 13]|
|                          [14, 15, 16]|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python version will be very similar:

```
// add unique id to each row
val df2 = df.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id).select('id, explode('tags).as("tag"))

val indexer = new StringIndexer()
  .setInputCol("tag")
  .setOutputCol("tagIndex")

val indexed = indexer.fit(df2).transform(df2)

// in the final step you should convert tags back to array of tags
val dfFinal = indexed.groupBy('id).agg(collect_list('tagIndex))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class, which will explode the array column, apply the StringIndexer, and will collect the indexes back to the list. The benefit of using it as a class instead of step by step transformations, is that it can be used in a pipeline or saved as fitted.

A class doing all the transformations and applying a StringIndexer:

```
class ArrayStringIndexerModel(Model
                              ,DefaultParamsReadable, DefaultParamsWritable):

    def __init__(self, indexer, inputCol: str, outputCol: str):
        super(ArrayStringIndexerModel, self).__init__()
        self.indexer = indexer
        self.inputCol = inputCol
        self.outputCol = outputCol

    def _transform(self, df: DataFrame=[]) -> DataFrame:

        # Creating always increasing id (as in fit)
        df = df.withColumn("id_temp_added", monotonically_increasing_id())\

        # Exploding "inputCol" and saving to the new dataframe (as in fit)
        df2 = df.withColumn('inputExpl', F.explode(self.inputCol)).select('id_temp_added', 'inputExpl')

        # Transforming with fitted "indexed"
        indexed_df = self.indexer.transform(df2)

        # Converting indexed back to array
        indexed_df = indexed_df.groupby('id_temp_added').agg(F.collect_list(F.col(self.outputCol)).alias(self.outputCol))

        # Joining to the main dataframe
        df = df.join(indexed_df, on='id_temp_added', how='left')

        # dropping created id column
        df = df.drop('id_temp_added')

        return df


class ArrayStringIndexer(Estimator
                ,DefaultParamsReadable, DefaultParamsWritable):
    """
    A custom Transformer which applies string indexer to the array of strings
    (explodes, applies StirngIndexer, aggregates back)
    """

    def __init__(self, inputCol: str, outputCol: str):
        super(ArrayStringIndexer, self).__init__()
       # self.indexer = None
        self.inputCol = inputCol
        self.outputCol = outputCol

    def _fit(self, df: DataFrame = []) -> ArrayStringIndexerModel:
        # Creating always increasing id
        df = df.withColumn("id_temp_added", monotonically_increasing_id())

        # Exploding "inputCol" and saving to the new dataframe
        df2 = df.withColumn('inputExpl', F.explode(self.inputCol)).select('id_temp_added', 'inputExpl')

        # Indexing self.indexer and self.indexed dataframe with exploded input column
        indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol='inputExpl', outputCol=self.outputCol)
        indexer = indexer.fit(df2)

        # Returns ArrayStringIndexerModel class with fitted StringIndexer, input and output columns
        return ArrayStringIndexerModel(indexer=indexer, inputCol=self.inputCol, outputCol=self.outputCol)
```

How to use the class in a code:

```
tags_indexer = ArrayStringIndexer(inputCol="tags", outputCol="tagsIndex")
tags_indexer.fit(df).transform(df).show()
```